# Array of pointers to an array of pointers to int

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

If i have array of pointer to an array of pointer to int

```
int **arrs = new int *[n];
```

and assign each element to new array of pointer to int

```
for i<n
 arrs[i] = new int[size]
```

Now, when i try to get size of these arrays, give me wrong value

```
int size = sizeof(arrs[0])/sizeof(int);
```

It gives me wrong value.
So how can i get the right value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `arrs[0]` is a pointer, so `sizeof(arrs[0])` gives the size of that pointer.

It comes as a surprise to some that there is **no way** to get the size of an array from only a pointer to that array. You have to store the size somewhere else.

In C++ the simplest and best solution is to use `std::vector`. Why reinvent the wheel? `std::vector` has everything you would want from a dynamic array, and should be the first choice in this situation.